# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function:

```
extractCountries: function() {
    var newCountries = [];
    _.forEach(this.props.countries, function(country) {

        var monthTemp = Utils.thisMonthTemp(parseFloat(country["name"]["temperature"]));

        if(parseFloat(country["name"]["safety"]) > this.state.minSafety &&
           parseFloat(country["name"]["nature"]) > this.state.minNature &&
           this.state.weather.min <= monthTemp &&
           monthTemp <= this.state.weather.max) {

            newCountries.push(country);
        }
    }).bind(this);
    return newCountries;
  }
```

On the line `parseFloat(country["name"]["safety"]) > this.state.minSafety &&` I get:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

But I am binding the external React object:

```
}).bind(this);
```

So why is this error occurring?

Comment: You're not binding the function itself. Move the `bind` call inside the parens. Currently you're calling `bind` on the return value of `_.forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
extractCountries: function() {
        var newCountries = [];
        _.forEach(this.props.countries, function(country) {

            var monthTemp = Utils.thisMonthTemp(parseFloat(country["name"]["temperature"]));

            if(parseFloat(country["name"]["safety"]) > this.state.minSafety &&
               parseFloat(country["name"]["nature"]) > this.state.minNature &&
               this.state.weather.min <= monthTemp &&
               monthTemp <= this.state.weather.max) {

                newCountries.push(country);
            }
        }, this );
        return newCountries;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mention in the comment you simply have to do this

```
extractCountries: function() {
    var newCountries = [];
    _.forEach(this.props.countries, function(country) {

        var monthTemp = Utils.thisMonthTemp(parseFloat(country["name"]["temperature"]));

        if(parseFloat(country["name"]["safety"]) > this.state.minSafety &&
           parseFloat(country["name"]["nature"]) > this.state.minNature &&
           this.state.weather.min <= monthTemp &&
           monthTemp <= this.state.weather.max) {

            newCountries.push(country);
        }
    }.bind(this));
    return newCountries;
  }
```